# How to do find weakly connected components using Cypher?

Tags: cypher, networkx, memgraphdb, opencypher

I'm trying to "translate" this Cypher query that uses NetworkX into pure Cypher. Can this even be achieved?

```
MATCH (n)-[e]->()
WITH collect(n) AS nodes, collect(e) AS edges
CALL wcc.get_components(nodes, edges) YIELD *
RETURN n_components, components;
```

Answer (score 0):

When using a neo4j DB, you can use the [Graph Data Science Library](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/), which can generate [weakly connected components](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/wcc/). The library plugin needs to be [installed](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/installation/) before you can use it.

The GDS library does all its processing in memory, for speed. So you first have to load the desired nodes/resources into memory before performing the wcc processing. For example, to load **all** the nodes and relationships into memory (only advisable for relatively small datasets):

```
CALL gds.graph.project.cypher(
  'allData',
  'MATCH (n) RETURN ID(n) AS id',
  'MATCH (n)-->(m) RETURN ID(n) AS source, ID(m) AS target')
```

Then, to get a wcc result similar to your query's:

```
CALL gds.wcc.stream('allData') YIELD nodeId, componentId
WITH componentId, COLLECT(nodeId) AS components
RETURN SIZE(components) AS n_components, components
```